# Handle deployment error for gcp dataflow pipeline in github actions

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, github-actions

I am deploying a gcp dataflow pipeline using `github actions`. Basically, I call a shell script which runs following command to deploy

```
python -m pipeline --project_id ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID} --job_name "pipeline-name"
```

This will deploy the pipeline and github action will show it as completed successfully, even if it fails it will be shown as successful. I want to bubble up the error if it fails. Now there are 2 ways to do so

1. Parse the command output of `python -m pipeline ...` command and see if it returns new pipeline link
2. use gcp cli to check if the new pipeline is created or not. this will need to be done in a loop with in a shell script.

The benefit of doing option 1 is that i can see if the pipeline has been created or not right away. However, if the gcp decide to change the url (since i will be using regex to get url), the script will break

The benefit of option 2 is that it will be more consistent with any underlying changes (unless cli tools get upgraded). But the problem in this is that i wouldn't know if the pipeline creation was successful or not, so i would have to go through a loop to find so and because of that, i can't drain existing pipeline unless it happens. The github action can show "in progress" for a minute or so.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a good usecase and beam has scope of improvement in deploying pipelines from automated tools.

If you are planning to update the same pipeline, you can potentially use update feature of Dataflow https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline so that you don't have to manually drain the pipeline.

Coming to option 1: The URL has been stable but I agree relying on any log format is prone to break over time.

2: It's possible to query dataflow and filter by job name https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/list You can use this to fetch the job and check the state of the job and creation time. However, this also seems to be flaky to me.